# Google analytics answer time

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Good day! We have many answer from GA
It start only today.

```
   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
    {
      "code" : 503,
      "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "message" : "There was a temporary error. Please try again later.",
        "reason" : "backendError"
      } ],
      "message" : "There was a temporary error. Please try again later."
```

And first time has "*[BLOCKED] " answer. We use 3 api version.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to be a little more specific in what you are trying to do and what you have tried already. Please read the [tips on how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it will help you get a good answer sooner. A good tip is to add some code so that we can see what you are trying to do and what the problems might be, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help. Good luck!

Comment: please supply a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve